# render() unexpected keyword error in Wagtail admin templates

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm in the process of upgrading from Django 1.11 and Wagtail 2.0 to latest versions of both. Everything seems to be working except when I try to edit or create one specific page type I get a Django error

```
File "/Users/########/new_blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  698.                 new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)

File "/Users/########/new_blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/templatetags/wagtailadmin_tags.py" in render_with_errors
  247.         return bound_field.as_widget()

File "/Users/########/new_blog/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/boundfield.py" in as_widget
  93.             renderer=self.form.renderer,

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/pages/6/edit/
Exception Value: render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'renderer'
```

Full stack trace here: https://gist.github.com/chrxr/0427c6f8bd884828bf332d7cf6290447

I'm sure this is to do with Django 2.0+ changes, and as its just one page I'm pretty sure its to do with my model, but I have no idea what part of the model could be causing this. Can anyone help me identify the issue?

The model in question is "Blogpage" and it can be seen here:

```
class BlogPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):
subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
main_image = models.ForeignKey(
    'wagtailimages.Image',
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='+'
)
date = models.DateField("Post date", null=True, blank=True)
intro = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
body = StreamField([
    ('heading', CharBlock(classname="full title", icon='title')),
    ('paragraph', RichTextBlock(icon='pilcrow')),
    ('image', ImageChooserBlock(icon='image')),
    ('codeblock', TextBlock(icon='cogs')),
    ('markdown', MarkDownBlock()),
    ('real_codeblock', CodeBlock()),
], blank=True, null=True)
tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True)
listing_intro = RichTextField(null=True, blank=True)
listing_image = models.ForeignKey(
    'wagtailimages.Image',
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name='+'
  )

search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
    index.SearchField('intro'),
    index.SearchField('body'),
]

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('subtitle'),
    ImageChooserPanel('main_image'),
    FieldPanel('date'),
    FieldPanel('intro'),
    StreamFieldPanel('body'),
    FieldPanel('tags'),
]

promote_panels = Page.promote_panels + [
    FieldPanel('listing_intro'),
    ImageChooserPanel('listing_image'),
]

@property
def home_page(self):
    return self.get_parent()

@property
def next_blog(self):
    blogs = BlogPage.objects.filter(live=True).order_by('-date')
    current_index = blogs.index(self)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return self.full_url

@route(r'^$', name='normal_blog')
def normal_blog(self, request):
    site_root = self.get_parent()

    return render(request, self.template, {
        'self': self,
    })

@route(r'^amp/$', name='amp_blog')
def amp_blog(self,request):
    context = self.get_context(request)
    context['is_amp'] = True
    context['base_template'] = 'base_amp.html'
    response = TemplateResponse(request, self.template, context)
    return response
```

In case it is useful, the full, 280 line models file can be seen here:

https://github.com/chrxr/blog_project/blob/upgrade-to-latest/blog/models.py#L118

I suspect its something to do with taggit, or at least I found some similar issues around that online, but I'm really not sure...

FWIW here is my requirements.txt

```
Django==2.1.7
Jinja2==2.8
Markdown==2.6.2
MarkupSafe==0.23
Pillow>2.8.2
PyYAML==3.11
Pygments==2.0.2
Unidecode==0.04.18
Willow>0.2.2
ansible==2.0.1.0
beautifulsoup4==4.4.0
django-appconf==1.0.3
django-compressor==1.5
django-medusa==0.3.0
django-modelcluster==4.1
django-sendfile==0.3.11
django-taggit==0.22.2
django-treebeard==4.0.1
djangorestframework==3.9.2
ecdsa==0.13
elasticsearch==6.3.1
google-api-python-client==1.5.0
html5lib==0.999
httplib2==0.9.2
oauth2client==2
paramiko==2.4.2
postgres==2.1.2
psycopg2==2.7.4
pyasn1==0.1.9
pyasn1-modules==0.0.8
pycrypto==2.6.1
python-memcached==1.59
pytz==2015.4
requests==2.7.0
rsa==3.3
simplejson==3.8.2
six==1.9.0
uritemplate==3.0.0
urllib3==1.24.1
wagtail==2.4
wagtailfontawesome==1.1.3
wheel==0.24.0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your code to the question instead of linking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to upgrade `django-taggit` to 0.23.0 - previous versions are [not compatible with Django 2.1](https://github.com/jazzband/django-taggit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst#0230-2018-08-07).